# Is it possible to use Time Machine with Airport Express + USB External Drive?

Tags: backup, time-machine, airport

I'm wondering if it's possible to connect an external USB drive to my Airport Express and then run Time Machine backups onto that? A bit like a makeshift Time Capsule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - airport express doesn't share drives, just printers.